# LocatorPane - restrict to circle

Tags: programming, dynamic

I have cobbled together a solution that does exactly what I need, but I don't fully understand how it works:

```
pts = {{2, 0}, {0, 2}};

LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts, (pts = #; pts = Function[{pnt}, If[Norm[pnt, 2] < 3, pnt,
    3*Normalize[pnt, (Norm[#, 2] &)]]] /@pts) &], Graphics[{LightGray, Disk[{0, 0}, 3]}, ImageSize -> 200]]
```

My goal is to have two locators constrained to a circle with a radius of 3.

I have a vague idea of the replacement operator `&` and the Map command `/@`, but there is too much going on at once. A step-by-step explanation is much appreciated.

What I *do* understand is the part inside the `If` clause: if the locator being dragged is still inside the disk those coordinates are returned, but if its coordinates have reached the edge of the disk it will stay there, restricting movement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dynamic` can have an expression followed by a single function evaluated during the interactive editing or a list of functions to be evaluated at various times (including before, during, and after interaction). What you have is essentially `Dynamic[expression, (function part 1; function part 2)&]`. The expression is the thing that needs to be updated—a list of points in this case.

Since you have the single function version, the function is evaluated essentially continuously as you move the locators around—any time the position of a locator changes, it is updated. In this case, the function (which is a compound expression connected by a semicolon) has two parts, even though you might be tempted to think of the function as the thing labeled `Function`.

First, `pts` is updated to be the current value by `pts = #`. The `&` after the closing parenthesis essentially feeds the value to the `#` (also called a `Slot`). The value that the `&` receives automatically from the system is a list of the current positions of the locators. This part is necessary since you have a second part where things might actually change, but if you didn't then `Dynamic[pts]` and `Dynamic[pts, (pts = #)&]` would be identical.

In the second part we have `pts = Function[{pnt}, If[Norm[pnt, 2] < 3, pnt, 3*Normalize[pnt, (Norm[#, 2] &)]]] /@ pts`. At the outermost level, we have `Function` that is being mapped (`/@`) onto the list `pts`. This means it takes each element from `pts` one at a time, applies the `Function` to each of them, and returns the list. In this case, `pts` is a list of two points. It feeds each point into the `Function` where it is temporarily renamed `pnt` for easy reference throughout the rest of the function. This `pnt` is then tested (first part of the `If`) to determine whether the 2-norm of `pnt` is less than 3. If that is true, the `pnt` is returned as-is (second part of the `If`) and nothing is done to it. If it is not true (3rd part of the `If`), it is outside the disk and `pnt` is modified to be the closest point which is within the disk before being returned. Finally, `pts` is updated with this newest list and Mathematica can then update the graphic.